# Flowtype, defining types inside classes

Tags: javascript, flowtype

```
class TodoFunctions {
  type TodoTy = { // ERROR : Unexpected identifier
    text:string;
    completed:boolean;
    id:number;
  };
  make(t:string,id:number):TodoTy{
    return {text:t,id:id,completed:false}
  }
  toggle(t:TodoTy):TodoTy {
    return {...t, completed:!t.completed};
  }
}
```

Is it possible to declare types inside classes? Like in Scala ? And then refer to them later as `TodoFunctions.TodoTy` ?

Comment: this seems relevant : https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/938

Comment: something like this seems to be possible https://flowtype.org/blog/2015/02/18/Import-Types.html

Comment: seems like it is not possible : https://flowtype.org/docs/modules.html#_ if it were it should be mentioned here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't believe this is possible. Types need to be defined at the top-level.

What I do is something like:

`export type TodoTy = ...`

and then wherever I need to use it in another module, do

`import type {TodoTy} from ...`

I understand this may not be quite as palatable as keeping the types tied more closely to where they are used, but in practice it works fine for me.